# Remove directory without `rm -r`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

How to remove non-empty directory without using `rm -r` or `find -delete` ?

I think it is related `to unlink`, `perl` or `inode`

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: @scai no problems, this is training task. I am looking for a way, remove or deleting files between C code and executable unix application, it is workable?

Comment: I see no training effect if you don't try it yourself. You already mentioned `unlink`. How about calling it for each file, and afterwards `rmdir` for each directory?

Answer (score 0):

Write some program in your programming language of choice:

```
python -c "import shutil; shutil.rmtree('your_dir_name')"
```